# Strange monomorphism of sheaves

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topologies

What is an example of a Grothendieck topology $J$ on a small category $\mathcal{C}$ such that the category of sheaves $\mathsf{Sh}(\mathcal{C},J)$ has a monomorphism which is not a monomorphism of presheaves (i.e. is *not* injective on sections)? Clearly $J$ cannot be subcanonical.

*Background.* In the book by Mac Lane - Moerdijk the proof that $\mathsf{Sh}(\mathcal{C},J)$ is an elementary topos, specifically in the proof that $\Omega_J$ is a subobject classifier, it seems to be used that subsheaves coincide with subobjects, without any assumption on $J$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inclusion $i \colon \mathsf{Sh}(\mathcal C,J) \hookrightarrow \hat{\mathcal C}$ has a left adjoint, namely the *sheafification functor*, hence preserves monomorphisms.

Comment: Ah, yes! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Specifically, if $F \to G$ is a monomorphism of sheaves, then for every $c \in C$ we have the sheaf $\hom(-,c)^\#$ associated to $\hom(-,c)$ and hence a monomorphism $F(c) \cong \hom(\hom(-,c)^\#,F) \to \hom(\hom(-,c)^\#,G) \cong G(c)$.